# Separate similar results from GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database that currently has all unique names, and I am porting a query from it to another database containing multiple similar names.

It selects the given name and family name of people in the database and displays information from them based on a unique id shared between two tables.

```
SELECT givenname, familyname
FROM table1 JOIN table2 USING (uniqueid)
GROUP BY givenname, familyname
```

This currently returns similar names into one result. I know I could use a subquery to return what I desire, but I am wondering if it possible without the use of a subselect / subquery.

Edit:

GROUP BY is there because it is using data from multiple tables with similar and dissimilar columns. I could use it with the uniqueid displaying, but i'd prefer not to.

Sample:

```
ID     Name         Result
1      John Smith    1
2      John Smith    1
3      Tony Nguyen   3   
4      Tony Nguyen   3
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to use `GROUP BY`, try removing it.

```
SELECT givenname, familyname
FROM   table1 
          JOIN table2 USING (uniqueid)
```

Comment: @user1644990 what do you exactly want to do? can you post sample results?